# Which statistical test should I use for a relationship between a continuous IV and a binary outcome? What about confounders?

Tags: regression, logistic, correlation, stata

I have a continuous independent variable ($x$) and binary dependent variable ($y$). I want to look at the relationship between them (I think I'd prefer regression to correlation) and I want to see how other variables (some continuous, some categorical) might confound the results?

Separately I also want to run another test looking at a continuous independent variable and ordinal dependent variable, also considering confounders. Which test do I use for this also?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! How would you do it for a continuous dependent variable? // I have made some edits to clarify your terminology. Please do change my edits if I have misinterpreted! // You have included the [tag:logistic] tag. Are you interested in logistic regression? If so, why?

Comment: That's okay! Well I thought logistic regression was supposed to be for binary outcomes and also more sophisticated than linear regression?

Comment: It’s not that logistic regression is more sophisticated than linear regression, just that linear regression and logistic regression address different problems. // How would you approach this problem if you had a continuous $y$ variable?

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what you mean. So can I use linear regression when I have a binary DV? And could you please elaborate on which problems they address? I just want to know whether the two variables are related to each other, which I know is really a correlation question, rather than a regression question, but because I also want to consider confounders, I am assuming I might have to do something like a multiple regression?

Comment: Some people actually do use linear regression with a binary $y$; it’s called a linear probability model. I have my concerns about it, but people do use such a model. // Please address how you would solve this kind of problem if you had a continuous $y$ variable.

Comment: Okay, wait what do you mean how would I solve this problem? I think that's what I'm asking really because I don't know haha!

Comment: For a continuous $y$, rather than the binary or ordinal $y$ you have to consider

Comment: Well if both the IV and DV are continuous, you would use linear regression right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, you remark that you would use a linear regression to model this for a continuous $y$ variable. This sounds like a reasonable idea, particularly since linear regression allows for nonlinear basis functions that introduce curvature (e.g., polynomials or splines) and interactions between variables.

Since you have a binary $y$, however, it is reasonable to model a slightly different way. A typical approach might be to use a generalized linear model like a logistic regression. A nice property of generalized linear models is that all of the tricks you can apply to the features in linear models also apply to generalized linear models. For the ordinal $y$, similar logic applies to a proportional odds ordinal logistic regression.

While you have commented that you seems to be more interested in correlation than regression, correlation is almost a special case of linear regression, so an extension to a regression framework seems acceptable.